# I need to hide an specific element of a navbar depending on a rol

Tags: laravel, navbar, roles, laravel-blade

I have a navbar and I have 2 elements outside the login option, the thing is that I need that a certain element stays with a certain role and when I'm not logged in...

Here is my code

```
<li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#services"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Explorar cursos</a>
        </li>            
        @if (Route::has('login'))
        @auth
        @role('Alumno')
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#about">Explorar cursos</a>
        </li>  
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="{{route('miscursos')}}"> Mis cursos</a>
        </li>
        @endrole
        @role('Administrador') 
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('home') }}" >
            {{ __('Tablero')}}
          </a>
        </li>
        @endrole
```

The second element on the list is the one I'm having problem with because I want it when I'm browsing in the page **but NOT logged in** and I need when I'm logged in with an 'Alumno' role

The thing is that I don't wanna see it when I'm logged in as an administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

Auth::guest() for conditional when user it not logged in. So if I am getting it right, in your second list element :

```
<?php 
@if(Auth::guest() || Auth::user()->role != 'Administrator)

// Only visible if user is NOT logged in OR logged in but not an administrator

@endif
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I changed the condition to AND and that worked fine